# Constraints on a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, matrix-equations

Let $a,\, b,\, c,\, d, \in \mathbb{R}$.  The $2\times2$ matrix acts on the pair of integers $(m_{i },\,n_{i})$ and gives a new pair of integers $(m_{j},n_{j})$:

$$\begin{align}
\left[ \begin{array}{c} m_{j} \\ n_{j} \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} 
a &  b  \\
c &  d
\end{bmatrix} \left[ \begin{array}{c} m_{i} \\ n_{i}  \end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

The determinant is assumed to be non-vanishing. The indices, $i$ and $j$ label the pairs: $i,j=1,2,3...$

Now suppose that for all values of $i$ and $j$, the ratios are bounded and satisfy: $\epsilon \geq m_{i}/n_{i} > 1$, $\epsilon \geq m_{j}/n_{j}>1$, where $\epsilon$ is some rational number.

Given this, what can be inferred about the $2\times2$ matrix above ? Can we put any constraints on its trace, determinant etc ?

Comment: Are your inequalities the right way around? You are saying that $\epsilon$ is a number greater than $1$?

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon > 1$

Comment: The way you're talking about $m_i$ and $n_i$ is a bit confusing. Are you saying that, for _any_ pair of integers with ratio satisfying your bounds, the result after applying the matrix also satisfies your bounds? Or are you saying that there's some list of particular pairs $(m_i, n_i)$ for which this happens?

Comment: No, there are no particular pairs $(m_{i},\, n_{i})$. Matrix preserves the bound for any pair that satisfies the given inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to rewrite your question slightly... You don't need to make it look as if you have a sequence of points.

Let $a,\, b,\, c,\, d, \in \mathbb{R}$.  The $2\times2$ matrix acts on the pair of integers $(m,n)$ and gives a new pair of integers $(m',n')$:

$$\begin{align}
\left[ \begin{array}{c} m' \\ n' \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} 
a &  b  \\
c &  d
\end{bmatrix} \left[ \begin{array}{c} m \\ n  \end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

The determinant is assumed to be non-vanishing.

Now suppose that for all pairs, the ratios are bounded and satisfy: $1 < m'/n' \le k$, provided we have the initial condition $1 < m/n \le k$, where $k$ is some rational number. [I don't like using $\epsilon$ for anything larger than $1$!]

Given this, what can be inferred about the $2\times2$ matrix above ? Can we put any constraints on its trace, determinant etc ?

Geometrically, you are starting with points between the lines $y=x$ and $y={x \over k}$ and you want to end up with points in the same area. You are not constraining the behaviour for points outside that area...

The initial constraint $1<m/n \le k$ can be rewritten as $m>n$ and $m \le kn$.

The constraint $1<m'/n' \le k$ can be rewritten as $m'>n'$ and $m' \le kn'$.

$m'>n' \Rightarrow am+bn>cm+dn$

$\Rightarrow am-cm>dn-bn$

$\Rightarrow (a-c)m>(d-b)n$

$\Rightarrow (a-c)>(d-b)$

$m' \le kn' \Rightarrow am+bn \le kcm+kdn$

$\Rightarrow am-kcm \le kdn-bn$

$\Rightarrow (a-kc)m \le (kd-b)n$

$\Rightarrow k(a-kc) \le (kd-b)$